# batchPoints with influxdb-java getting overwritten unless forced unique time?

Tags: java, influxdb

My project is currently using [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java) to connect to Influx 1.8.2. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
InfluxDB connection = InfluxDBFactory.connect(server, client);
connection.enableBatch(100,10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
connection.setDatabase(database);
BatchPoints batchPoints = BatchPoints.database(database).build();

long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis()*1000000;
double[] data1 = getInfluxData();
for (int i=someInt; i < data1.length; i++){
    if (i % someInt == 0){
        double[] data2 = processData(data1, i-someInt, i);
        for (int j=0; j < data2.length; j++){
            Point p = Point.measurement(someTable)
                .time(currTime+i+j, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)   //Line A (j < someInt)
                .tag("someTag", "someTagValue")
                .addField("someField", data2[j])
                .build();
            batchPoints.point(p)
        }
}
connection.write(batchPoints);
connection.disableBatch();
connection.close();
```

Currently, `Line A` needs to be present, otherwise it seems my points overwrite themselves and only 1 point will actually get written out to `someTable`. Thus, `Line A` is a hacky solution but it's the only way I can get all points written out. The inspiration for the use of batchPoints like this came from influx's own [example performance tests](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/influxdb/PerformanceTests.java) where they don't even specify a time. So what am I doing wrong that's causing the points to overwrite if not for `Line A`? Might be switching [influxdb-client-java](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java) instead, just for context, in case that might alleviate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Isaac -

If you are using InfluxDB 1.8+, I would consider switching to the `influxdb-client-java` as it seems more frequently maintained.

For your code sample using `influxdb-java`, the BatchPoints builder is not being used idiomatically. I'd say `testWritePerformance` in the example tests is also strange and that test is disabled.

I'm eliding much of your code.

```java
// setup ...

BatchPoints.Builder batchPointsBuilder = BatchPoints.database(database);

// start for loops ...

batchPointsBuilder.point(p);

// finish loops ...

connection.write(batchPointsBuilder.build());


// setdown
```

BUT looking at the java code and yours, I don't think this is the problem as `point(Point p)` is appending `Point`s to a `List`. So it shouldn't be overwriting here.

If you leave out the timestamp, all the points will get the same timestamp because the batch arrives all at once (this is how a left out timestamp is determined in InfluxDB - when the Point arrives). I can't see your data and tags but if all the points are identical with fields keys, tags keys, tag values, and timestamp, then they will overwrite/replace each other. I suspect your data/tags/fields are supposed to be different; double check it.

Lastly, I'd have you check (and share if you will) how you know that all the points are overwriting themselves? What is the query you are using?

~There's a typo in your sample code at `for (int i=someInt; i < data.length; i++){` - should be `data1`.~

Comment: After writing the points I ran the `SELECT COUNT("value") FROM someTable` and saw the result was just 1. The tags would've been the same but they had different values in the fields but some by coincidence might've had the same values so I can see how those could've been overwritten. 

I can switch to `influxdb-client-java` but why do you suggest I switch to that if my code is already written using `influxdb-java`? I know you can use flux but are there writing performance advantages?

I've corrected my typo. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like if I were to switch to `influxdb-client-java`, I'd have to switch to Flux to make queries.

Comment: `influxdb-client-java` seemed better maintained - that's all. There is a `/query` endpoint on InfluxDB2 that accepts InfluxQL queries. I'm not sure if the java client exposes that. "definitely" switch was perhaps too strong.

Comment: Can you explain better this  "idiomatic use" of `BatchBuilder`? I changed my code to your example and I'm getting the issue found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55851725/influxdb-java-org-influxdb-influxdbioexception-java-net-socketexception-conne except this "solution" is not like yours.

Comment: Also - it's the tag keys, tag values, and field keys and timestamp that define a Point within a measurement. If the field values are different but everything else is the same, influx is treating that as an overwrite/replace. Is there a meaningful timestamp that applies to your data? It's a time series, right? The time sequence part is critical. My answer wasn't 100% clear here - I'll edit it.

Comment: By idiomatic, I meant "java builder pattern" which is `MyObjBuilder b = new MyObBuilder(); b.add(value1); b.add(value2); b.add(value3); MyOb o = b.build(); send(o);` Are you getting the `socket write error` in that post? It looks like that happens when the server is getting too many request: see https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-the-client-responds-to-concurrent-write-backpressure-from-server Try fewer points in a Batch. This error is unrelated to my builder pattern suggestion (it's just a suggestion - not critical).

Answer (score 1):

In InfluxDB all points having same tag values and timestamp even when having different field values are considered to be duplicate. So such data points are silently overwritten. This is as per the InfluxDB  [design](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4150#issuecomment-141186561).

```
Is it a limitation of influx that only one point can exist with the same tags and timestamp?
```

> Yes, this is by design.
>
> ```
> If a collision does occur, does the old one get overwritten?
> ```
>
> Yes, it is silently overwritten.
>
> This is documented but not well. I opened influxdata/influxdb.com#324
> to address that.